# when creating note in evernote how to attach PDF resource with note (android application)

Tags: android, api, evernote

when creating note in evernote how to attach PDF resource  with note (android application).how to create resource list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code adapted from the ImagePicker sample found in Evernote's Android SDK which can be found in samples/HelloEDAM/src/com/evernote/android/sample/ImagePicker.java lines 197 to 228

[Here is a link](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-android/blob/b2652fde9cff3e50888fbffffa2d3349c8048851/samples/HelloEDAM/src/com/evernote/android/sample/ImagePicker.java#L197) to the relevent file and line on Evernote's Github account where they host all their SDKs.

```
// Hash the data in the PDF file. The hash is used to reference the
// file in the ENML note content.
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
FileData data = new FileData(EvernoteUtil.hash(in), new File(f));
in.close();

// Create a new Resource
Resource resource = new Resource();
resource.setData(data);
resource.setMime(mPDFdata.mimeType);
ResourceAttributes attributes = new ResourceAttributes();
attributes.setFileName(mPDFdata.fileName);
resource.setAttributes(attributes);

// Create a new Note
Note note = new Note();
note.setTitle("Android test note");
note.addToResources(resource);

// Set the note's ENML content. Learn about ENML at
// http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/ENML.php
String content =
    EvernoteUtil.NOTE_PREFIX +
        "<p>This note was uploaded from Android. It contains an PDF.</p>" +
        EvernoteUtil.createEnMediaTag(resource) +
        EvernoteUtil.NOTE_SUFFIX;

note.setContent(content);

if(!mEvernoteSession.getAuthenticationResult().isAppLinkedNotebook()) {
  // Create the note on the server. The returned Note object
  // will contain server-generated attributes such as the note's
  // unique ID (GUID), the Resource's GUID, and the creation and update time.

  mEvernoteSession.getClientFactory().createNoteStoreClient().createNote(note, mCreateImageCallback);
} else {
  super.createNoteInAppLinkedNotebook(note, mCreateImageCallback);
}
```